# Detect if a function was executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
function enviarMail() {
    for (var x = 1; x <= idShort; x++) {
        var nume = $('#Num' + x).text();
        var purp = $('#Pur' + x).text();
        var open = $('#Open' + x).text();
        var close = $('#Close' + x).text();
        var owner = $('#Owner' + x).text();
        var fam = $('#Fam' + x).text();
        var vs = $('#Vs' + x).text();
        var sta = $('#Sta' + x).text();
        var mail = $('#Mail' + x).text();    

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', //POST | GET
                url: urlServer + 'ws_alerts.asmx/SendMailExp',
                data: '{"us":"' + owner +
                    '","email":"' + mail +
                    '","vs":"' + vs +
                    '","fam":"' + fam +
                    '","pur":"' + purp +
                    '","open":"' + open +
                    '","close":"' + close +
                    '","id":"' + nume + '"}', 
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                timeout: 600000,
                error: function (xhr) {
                    bootbox.alert("No se pudo enviar el correo.");
                },
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
    }
}
```

I call this function on (document).ready, works fine! but I only want to execute this function 1 time for example I log in at 8:00am the function is going to be executed, then if I log in again at 9:15am the function going to be executed again and I do not want my email full of this mail, so my question is how can I do to execute the function 1 time per day.

PD. Function is executed on main page, so a lot of users can execute the function, but I only want to execute it 1 time doesn't matter which user do it.

PD2. I was thinking in a timer but, the users can access from any device, so I don't know if this can work (for example I log in from my PC and the timer starts, then I log in from my Tablet and what happen with the timer? I'm going to have another time of it's going to be the same from PC?)

Comment: Execute it only one time for all users, not once for each user? You need to maintain state on the server. The function needs to perform an AJAX call to find out if any other users have run the function that day.

Comment: With your requirements I believe you need to do this in conjunction with backend script and DB or a cron job

Comment: You need a server for this. You have an application server?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, one time for all users.

Comment: So this only can be possible using server side right? Maybe I can use a MySQL event/MSSQL Job?

Comment: You don't need anything like that. Just a table where you store the last time the function was run. When the next user logs in, check if the date was the same day.

Comment: can you manipulate the code in ws_alerts.asmx ?

Comment: @leonskb4 Yes, I can

Comment: @Barmar You should post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for needs to be enforced from the server side. As clients can log in (like you mentioned) at any time from any device, it is not possible to maintain this on the client side.

What you want is to somehow maintain state across all clients. You need to use `cookies` or `session` to do this, as these provide sharing of state between different clients and the server. As there is only one server(theoretically), it can be programmed to be aware whether an operation has been performed for a user in a day. This flag can be then shared across to all clients through `session`/`cookie`

**Note:** *This is all assuming that you have some kind of authentication/session that can be shared between the server and your client. Otherwise, there is no way that the server can recognize you when you open the client form different devices/browsers*

The process can be as follows:

- The user logs in from ClientA. On the server side, (either in a in-memory store like Redis or Memcache, or in a DB), the server checks for the user's id to see if the `functionTriggered` is true already. If no, in the auth response, the server sends the `functionTriggered=false` flag (sets a cookie on the client)
- ClientA makes the AJAX call and the server sets `functionTriggered=true` in the store
- The user logs in from ClientB. Upon login, the server sees that `functionTriggered=true`, therefore, sends this flag. Server sets a cookie indicating this. The client sees this and skips the AJAX request.

Comment: Cookies and sessions are per-client, so they can't be used for this.

Comment: @Barmar Consider a situation where a user logs in from a device. Their auth/session details (`functionTriggered`) will be available to the server now. This can be stored either in the DB or a in memory store like Redis. Now, if they login from another device, they will request auth from the server, and when the server responds, it can send back the `functionTriggered` flag along with the auth details couldn't it?

Comment: If they login from a different device, they won't be in the same session, so there won't be any auth/session details.

Comment: @Barmar I've edited my answer with the steps I think would work. Could you tell me if you find any flaws in the thought process?

Comment: Now I see what you're saying: use the store to keep track of logins between different clients, and then use a cookie on the client to remember that it already checked earlier, so it doesn't need to check with the server every time.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @DustinToothless but in contrary to what Dustin said I would suggest making a separate call (to keep things separate and maintain software engineering principals) to the server requesting whether it is OK to send the AJAX call or not. The server, however, would make the decision based on whether it had previously received a request or not -- that can accomplished by using a database or using a file comparing the last modified date (this way you can also log) -- and if it already received a request then the server would give the OK to execute the AJAX call.

Although, the above would work but it not efficient or secure since the client could potentially send the AJAX request regardless of what the server says (i.e. a hacker could cause a DoS attack) therefore, you should only use one function (this call even) and let the server decide (using the method above) whether to send the email or not.